# Flow, object literal incompatible with union

Tags: javascript, flowtype

If I have a function that returns either an object with information from the database or an empty object like this:

```
getThingFromDB: async function(id:string):Promise<EventObj|Empty>{
    const fromDB = await dao.getEvent(id);
    if(fromDB && fromDB.length){
        return fromDB[0];
    }
    return {};

}
```

I get a lot of Flow errors like:

```
return {};
       ^^ object literal. This type is incompatible with
getThingFromDB: async function(id:string):Promise<EventObj|Empty>{                                                                                
                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ union: EventObj | Empty
```

Or

```
getThingFromDB: async function(id:string):Promise<EventObj|Empty>                                                                                      
                                                  ^^^^^^^^ property `id`. Property not found in
return {};
       ^^ object literal
```

Here are my declared object types.

```
declare type EventObj = {
    id:string,
    name:string,
    urlName:string
};

declare type Empty = {||};
```

What am I missing? How do I properly satisfy these errors.

Comment: Try to annotate explicitly inside the function's body. I guess flow has trouble to infer the types of the return values due to the conditional branching (try to remove the branching or freeze/seal the object literal `return Object.freeze({});`)

Comment: `Object.freeze({});` did the trick, thank you! If you change this to an answer, I would accept it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible patch consists of sealing/freezing the empty `Object` literal. But this only bypasses the underlying issue: You've defined an exact `Object` type though you only need a sealed one:

```
type Empty = {};

let o = {};
let p = {foo: true};
let q: Empty = {};

o.foo = true; // type checks
p.bar = true; // type error
q.foo = true; // type error
```

You can see that only the empty object literal is an unsealed `Object` type in flow. Exact `Object` types are unnecessary at this point and you can safely remove the exact type annotation from `{||}`. What are they useful for then?

```
type Foo = {|foo: boolean|};
type Bar = {bar: boolean};

const f = (o: Foo) => o;
const g = (o: Bar) => o;

f({foo: true, bar: true}); // type error
let o = g({foo: true, bar: true}); // type checks

o.foo; // type error
```

With exact `Object` types you have a finer control over width subtyping.

However, width subtyping comes with its own pitfalls, because it erase type information as you can see by the failing property access `o.foo`.